# Paypal button terminates asp .net execution after approved purchase

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, paypal, jscript

When I test in the paypal sandbox with smart buttons with generated code from paypal, the purchase is successfully executed. **BUT when I redirect** to a successful purchase page, the asp .net engine in debug, crashes and then does not execute the server code (like sending successful purchase email to the customer, saving the paypal transaction id in the database, etc).
I tested with window.location, window.location.href, window.location.replace, etc ... the page redirects but does not execute the code behind it. Maybe it executes 1 or 2 lines of code and then stops immediately, other times it gets the error that localhost rejects the connection.

By Example, this code not crash (debug and code behind of paypalok.aspx runs ok)

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs"        
   Inherits="WebApplication8.WebForm1" %>

   <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
   <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="redirect()" />
    </div>
  </form>

<script>
    function redirect() {
        window.location.href = 'paypalok.aspx';
    }
  </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

You can try it yourself and you will see how the asp .net debug stops unexpectedly after the redirection to 'paypalok.aspx'.

by Example, this code crash:...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="paypal3.aspx.cs"               
                        Inherits="WebApplication7.paypal3" %>

      <!DOCTYPE html>

       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head runat="server">
      <title></title>
    </head>
  <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="smart-button-container">
          <div style="text-align: center;">
            <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&enable-funding=venmo&currency=USD"       
     data-sdk-integration-source="button-factory"></script>
    <script>
        function initPayPalButton() {

      paypal.Buttons({
          style: {
              shape: 'rect',
              color: 'gold',
              layout: 'vertical',
              label: 'paypal',

          },

          createOrder: function (data, actions) {
              return actions.order.create({
                  purchase_units: [{ "amount": { "currency_code": "USD", "value": 0.81 } }]
              });
          },

          onApprove: function (data, actions) {
              window.location.replace ('paypalok.aspx');
          },

          onError: function (err) {
              console.log(err);
          }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  }

        initPayPalButton();

        </script>



  </body>
  </html>
```

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You should not create orders on the client side and then capture on a server. Don't mix these integration types. Also it is best for your server's capture route to simply reply with JSON so you can call it with fetch/XHR, rather than redirecting, and show an immediate success/thank you message. There's no good reason to redirect away on a modern website.

---

Follow the [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) guide and make 2 routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). Both routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Inside the 2nd route, when the capture API is successful you should store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, which is the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller.

Pair those 2 routes with the frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Note that this flow includes proper client-side error handling in the event a funding instrument is declined, which is important. Redirecting away does not allow the user to retry gracefully, and should be avoided.